# How to setup ROS environment variable on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) guide to install ROS, but even after adding ROS source.list and its key

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

gave error.

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

Then I ran this command

```
sudo apt search ros
```

to see if any such package exists. I couldn't find `ros-melodic-desktop-full` but I found another similar package `ros-desktop-full`.
So I installed it instead. The installation went smooth without giving any errors.

Next step in the guide is to set-up ROS environment variable, but I have no such directory

```
/opt/ros
```

So how do I setup the environment variable?

**P.S.**

I also installed some tools and dependencies with this command

```
sudo apt install python3-rosdep python3-rosinstall python3-rosinstall-generator python3-wstool build-essential
```

and initialized `rosdep`

```
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351321/how-to-setup-ros-environment-variable-on-ubuntu-20.04?/) by [AkashKarnatak](https://answers.ros.org/users/54384/akashkarnatak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I tried following [this][1] guide to install ROS, but even after adding ROS source.list and its key
>
> ```
> sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
> ```
>
> gave error.
>
> ```
> E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full
> ```

For this, see #q350668 (which is a duplicate of your initial question), and refer to the linked #q350055 as well.

Summarising: ROS Melodic is not supported on Ubuntu `20.04`.

> Then I ran this command
>
> ```
> sudo apt search ros
> ```
>
> to see if any such package exists. I couldn't find `ros-melodic-desktop-full` but I found another similar package `ros-desktop-full`.
> So I installed it instead. The installation went smooth without giving any errors.

This will not get you ROS Melodic, nor any other specific ROS version.

Refer to [wiki/UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages) for information on what you installed with that command.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1